# Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to show 'app': Operation not supported

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was trying to configure the NDT mapping/matching algorithm, I clicked on the 'app' icon. But the terminal shows

```
(runtime_manager_dialog.py:18020): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to show 'app': Operation not supported
```

Why is this?

My system: Ubuntu 16.04
ROS version: kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327053/gtk-warning-**:-unable-to-show-%27app%27:-operation-not-supported/) by [Jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/43538/jasmine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-06-26**:
Can you please provide more details?
Autoware version? (Commit)
Are you using Docker?

**Comment by [Jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/43538/jasmine/) on 2019-06-27**:
Hello,
Thanks for replying.
I am not using Docker, and btw, how do I check the Autoware version?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-27**:
If you downloaded the Autoware repo, go to that folder and run `git status` and post the output here. If you are using the latest version with the install instructions from https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build then go into your autoware workspace's source folder (~/autoware.ai/src) and into a main sub-folder (e.g. autoware/utilities) and run `git status` and post the output here.

**Comment by [Jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/43538/jasmine/) on 2019-06-27**:
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   ros/run
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

The output is like this.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-27**:
Which folder did you do that in? Can you give me the full path to it? Also, can you do `git fetch` and then `git status` again?

**Comment by [Jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/43538/jasmine/) on 2019-06-27**:
I did this inside the folder /Autoware.

mist@mist-XPS-8930:~/Autoware$ git fetch
remote: A repository for this project does not exist yet.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/CPFL/Autoware.git/' not found
mist@mist-XPS-8930:~/Autoware$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   ros/run
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are on a very old version of Autoware. The Autoware project has changed URLs a few times but the proper URL for the current version is https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware. Previous URLs include:

- https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware
- https://github.com/CPFL/autoware

If you have either of these, you will need to update your repository to point to the URL in the paragraph above. Please note that, as of version 1.12.0-alpha.1, the primary Autoware repository has been split up. You can find all new repositories at https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai. For install instructions for the latest version, see https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Installation. As 1.12 is not yet ready for release, these instructions do not include installation instructions for older versions - we are working on this. For now, you can do the following to get an older version:

```
cd ~
git clone https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware.git
cd autoware
git checkout 1.11.1 (or whatever version you want to go back to)
cd ros
```

For build instructions, see step 4 and below of https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/43538/jasmine/) on 2019-06-30**:
Thanks so much.